# Problem with reading JSON object inside react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

In my project i have 3 components, first is searchbar that is used for inputting value for API, second is mainPage, which connects everything and sends searched value to API  and the last one is weatherView used for showing json data. Unfortunaly, I can't display data from that JSON object.

First, component that is used to input value, then send it to mainPage:

```
const SearchBarComponent = (props: {handleSearch: Function}) => {
const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState('');
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState<Object>();

const handleSubmitEvent = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.handleSearch(searchVal);

}
const handleSearchingOnChange = (arg: string) =>{
    if(arg !== '')
    {
        return fetch(`${apiOptions.url}${arg}&limit=10&min_population=100000`, apiOptions)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => setDataList(Object.keys(json).map((k, i) =>
            <div key={i} className="bg-light">
                <p className="font-weight-bold"> {json[i].name} - {json[i].country}</p>
            </div>
        )))
        .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));
    }
   
}

const searchForm =  <div className="border-dark d-block m-20">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmitEvent}>
        <input type="text" value={searchVal} onChange={(e) => setSearchVal(e.target.value)} onInput={() => handleSearchingOnChange(searchVal)} />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary">Szukaj!</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    


return (
    <>
        <div className="d-Block">
            <>
                {searchForm}
                {dataList}
            </>
        </div>
    </>
    
);
}

export default SearchBarComponent;
```

Second, mainPage componentm that connects to API and sends response to WeatherView as prop:

```
const MainPageComponent = () => {
const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState(Object);

useEffect(() => {
    
}, [currentLocation]);

const handleSearch = (arg: string) => {
    return fetch(`${weatherApiOptions.url}?key=${weatherApiOptions.key}&q=${arg}&aqi=no`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => setCurrentLocation(json))
    .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));
}


return (
    <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <SearchBarComponent handleSearch={handleSearch}/>
        <WeatherView currentPlace={currentLocation}/>
    </div>
);
}

export default MainPageComponent;
```

And lastly, component that should display data from json object in prop:

```
const WeatherView = (props: {currentPlace: Object}) => {

    console.log(props.currentPlace);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{props.currentPlace.current} </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default WeatherView;
```

this is my json object:

[image: this is my json object]

I can't read it in weatherView, both {props.currentPlace.SOMETHING} and {props.currectPlace["SOMETHING"]} do not work.

Comment: _"this is my json object:"_, no, that's a JavaScript object, not JSON

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(props.currentPlace.current)`? Object as children is not supported

Answer (score -1):

You cannot directly pass an object as a child. You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to get a string representation.

```
<p>{JSON.stringify(props.currentPlace.current)}</p>
```

Or, for better formatting:

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(props.currentPlace.current, null, 4)}</pre>
```

Comment: It is working, but now, how can i access the specific fields, after trying something like 

<pre>{JSON.stringify(props.currentPlace.current.location, null, 4)}</pre> i get an error:
"caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')", for some reason i can only access it with ".current" and overall it still highlights as error.

Comment: @Kamil If you're trying to access the location object, it should be `props.currentPlace.location`

Comment: Also note that you don't need `JSON.stringify` if the field is not an object, like a string or number.